# Subset and For Loop in Mice

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, subset, r-mice

I'm trying to run MICE imputations based on a unique list of values in my dataset. To illustrate my problem, I will use the 'airquality' dataset since it has NA values. I'm trying to loop through all the unique months and impute that subset and ultimately add all of the imputed datasets to a blank data frame.

For some reason I always get this error,

```
Error in filter(., Month == i) : object '*tmp*' not found
```

Here is the code below:

```
data("airquality")
library(mice)
library(dplyr)

#create a list for the unique months
month_list = unique(airquality$Month)

initial_imputed_complete <- data.frame()

for (i in month_list){
  airquality %>% filter(Month == i) %>%
    airquality[[i]] <- mice(airquality, m = 1, maxit = 1, meth = "norm", seed = 3985)
    initial_imputed_complete[[i]] <- as.data.frame(complete(airquality[[i]]))
    write.csv(initial_imputed_complete[[i]], file = paste0("Imputation", i))
    
}
```

In the console, I can see the imputation occurring so the filtering process works for the first i in the month list.

Comment: Did you created a list by the same name `airquality` for storing the output

Comment: You seem to be piping `%>%` data into an assignment `<-` which does not look correct. Maybe you want something more like `airquality[[i]] <- mice(airquality %>% filter(Month == i), m = 1, maxit = 1, meth = "norm", seed = 3985))`. But also be sure the initialize the `airquality` list.

Comment: @MrFlick The pipping was the issue. I've posted a solution to my question below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by two simple things to do prior:

- Initialize the list for both `airquality_impute` & `intial_imputed_complete`.
- Piping in the data assignment in MICE rather than doing it prior to the function. See @MrFlick's comments in the question.

I am now getting the outputs saved for the subset imputing for the different months. See solved code below.

```
data("airquality")
library(mice)
library(dplyr)

#create a list for the unique months
month_list = unique(airquality$Month)

airquality_impute <- list()
initial_imputed_complete <- list()

for (i in month_list){
    airquality_impute[[i]] <- mice(airquality %>% filter(Month == i), m = 1, maxit = 1, meth = "norm", seed = 3985)
    initial_imputed_complete[[i]] <- complete(airquality_impute[[i]])
    write.csv(initial_imputed_complete[[i]], file = paste0("Imputation", i, ".csv"))
    
}
```